# BeautifulSoup4: Missing Parsed Table Data

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to extract the Earnings Per Share data through BeautifulSoup 4 from [this page](http://financials.morningstar.com/ratios/r.html?t=AAPL&region=usa&culture=en-US).

When I parse the data, the table information is missing using the default, `lxml` and HTML 5 parsers. I believe this has something to do with Javascript and I have been trying to implement `PyV8` to transform the script into readable HTML for BS4. The problem is I don't know where to go from here.

Do you know if this is in fact my issue? I have been reading many posts and it's been a very big headache for me today. Below is a quick example. The `financeWrap` includes the table information, but beautifulSoup shows that it is empty.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "http://financials.morningstar.com/ratios/r.html?t=AAPL&region=usa&culture=en-US"

response = requests.get(url)
soup_key_ratios = bs(response.content, 'html5lib')
financial_tables = soup_key_ratios.find("div", {"id":"financeWrap"})
print financial_tables

# Output: <div id="financeWrap">
#           </div>
```

Comment: @Begueradj That is a funny observation. I've found that normally if you look hard enough you can find the answer!

Comment: @BryceDoganer Tag your question with `beautifulsoup`. It will help you to receive a good answer quickly.

Comment: Perhaps I'm missing something, but is there any reason why `http://...en-US` isn't quoted as a string?

Comment: @alexwlchan in my code it is in quotes, I forgot to add it here. It has been edited

Comment: use chrome visit: `view-source:http://financials.morningstar.com/ratios/r.html?t=AAPL&region=usa&culture=en-US`, you will found that bs4 is nothing wrong

Comment: That is to say, the website display the data use `Javascipt`, you should find where it is and analysis the js code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that you're trying to get data that is coming in through Ajax on the website. If you go to the link you provided, and looked at the source via the browser, you'll see that there should be no content with the data.

However, if you use a console manager, such as [Firebug](https://getfirebug.com/), you will see that there are Ajax requests made to the following [URL](http://financials.morningstar.com/financials/getFinancePart.html?&callback=jsonp1413893091189&t=XNAS:AAPL&region=usa&culture=en-US&cur=&order=asc&_=1413893091310), which is something you can parse via beautifulsoup (perhaps - I haven't tried it or looked at the structure of the data).

Keep in mind that this is quite possibly against the website's ToS.

Comment: Great! This is what I want to say.

Comment: @Duniyadnd Thank you for pointing that out. I figured it had to be related to something along those lines, I just didn't know how to find the request links. I'm going to look into Firebug and also see about the ToS.